# How do I create an iso from a mounted hdd in a live linux?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, backup, external-hdd

I'm aware I can use clonezilla for that, but that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm booting from an USB device. In terminal I'm doing `sudo cat /dev/sdf2 > ~/file.iso`, and that works. But it's creating the .iso on the USB stick.

`sdf2` being the HDD I want an .iso of (which is docked in an usb3 dock). `sdb` being my internal archive HDD. I want the ISO to be created in another volume, which is `/dev/sdb`.

`sudo cat /dev/sdf2 > /dev/sdb/file.iso`

`sudo cat /dev/sdf2 > /dev/sdb/~/file.iso`

`sudo cat /dev/sdf2 > /dev/sdb/x/file.iso`

Nothing works, always "no directory".

Comment: Do you want an iso file or image file on the other device, or do you want to make the other device (`/dev/sdb`) a USB boot drive? Please notice that an image of a partition, which you describe in your question is *not* an iso file in the meaning, that it can be cloned to make a bootable CD/DVD/USB drive. An iso file needs a bootloader too, and for it to work from a USB drive also a partition structure.

Comment: The sdf2 is my old system hdd (win 7). I just want a complete image from it, so I can browse in my new system and check what apps, etc. I had installed. The sdf2 is mounted via an usb dock. The sdb is my other internal archive hdd.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands are not working because you are trying to create a file or folder in a block-device. A block-device is a special file, you cannot create a file or folder in it, it's not a directory. `/dev/sdb` is a block-device:

```
~$ ls -l /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Aug  8 10:11 /dev/sdb
```

Look at the first letter of the permissions, it's *b* for *block-device*, not *d* for *directory*.

If you would run `sudo cat /dev/sdf2 > /dev/sdb`, that would work, but would relentless destroy any file-system that's already stored on that drive, you don't want to do that.

Instead, when booted into the live system, mount the partition where you want to store the output-file:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdbx /mnt
```

and then use

```
sudo cat /dev/sdf2 > /mnt/path/to/folder/filename/of/your/choice
```

Answer (score 0):

... I believe what you are looking for is in the manuals for
another partition with a copy of `sdf2` in, lets say, `sdf4` maybe?

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

... see what you have available first.
Gparted - partition create and resizing, `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdf4` (-I if needed )
and ... now try it ^__^

... the problem creates its own errors with anything newer than Windows 3.10
and those Security WIN32 files - these argue strongly on Windows 95 and newer.
This should let you play with `sdf2` to your hearts content. ( just a thought )